# display numbers of rows with wrong amount of fields

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have csv file. first row shows fields' names it has correct amount of fields. i have to display ids/numbers of rows which have incorrect amount of fields.
My code:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="\n"; FS="\t" }  {c; if(NR==1){c=NF} print c; if(NR>1){if(NF!=c){print NR}} } ' ./cities.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
awk -F '\t' '
    NR == 1 {num_fields = NF}
    NF != num_fields {print NR}
' file
```

Comment: For more info about awk; click [tag:awk] then click the "Learn more" link.

Comment: it doesn't show failures, but it doesn't show any result

Comment: Then all the records have the same number of fields.